# listoffigures without dots and hfill for pagenumbers

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrbook

I'm using documentclass scrbook and want to remove the dotted lines and hfill for page numbers in a List of Figures.

Something similar to what this does for the table of contents:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  toclinefill=\quad,
  tocraggedpagenumber=true,
]{part,chapter,section,subsection}
```

I think it's a simple question, but I've not found a specific discussion or solution here. Any hints are highly appreciated. I'm sorry if I'm doubling something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the macro `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` contained in KOMA. With it you can do the following:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[linefill=\quad,raggedpagenumber=true]{tocline}{figure}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}% >>>
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%
  \caption
  {%
    A Friendly Duck%
    \label{fig:duck}%
  }%
\end{figure}% <<<

\end{document}
```